# How can I read the received packets with a NDIS filter driver?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, windows-kernel, ndis

I am currently experimenting with the [NDIS driver samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/ndis/filter).
I am trying to print the packets contents (including the MAC-addresses, EtherType and the data).

My first guess was to implement this in the function [`FilterReceiveNetBufferLists`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/dbadff83eed662c244d5a6fae48baa840fb543b8/network/ndis/filter/filter.c#L1434). Unfortunately I am not sure how to extract the packets contents out of the `NetBufferLists`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the right place to start.  Consider this code:

```
void FilterReceiveNetBufferLists(..., NET_BUFFER_LIST *nblChain, ...)
{
    UCHAR buffer[14];
    UCHAR *header;

    for (NET_BUFFER_LIST *nbl = nblChain; nbl; nbl = nbl->Next) {
        header = NdisGetDataBuffer(nbl->FirstNetBuffer, sizeof(buffer), buffer, 1, 1);
        if (!header)
            continue;

        DbgPrint("MAC address: %02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x-%02x\n",
            header[0], header[1], header[2],
            header[3], header[4], header[5]);
    }

    NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists(..., nblChain, ...);
}
```

There are a few points to consider about this code.

The NDIS datapath uses the NET_BUFFER_LIST (nbl) as its primary data structure.  An nbl represents a set of packets that all have the same metadata.  For the receive path, nobody really knows much about the metadata, so that set always has exactly 1 packet in it.  In other words, the nbl is a list... of length 1.  For the receive path, you can count on it.

The nbl is a list of one or more NET_BUFFER (nb) structures.  An nb represents a single network frame (subject to LSO or RSC).  So the nb corresponds most closely to what you think of as a packet.  Its metadata is stored on the nbl that contains it.

Within an nb, the actual packet payload is stored as one or more buffers, each represented as an MDL.  Mentally, you should pretend the MDLs are just concatenated together.  For example, the network headers might be in one MDL, while the rest of the payload might be in another MDL.

Finally, for performance, NDIS gives as many NBLs to your LWF as possible.  This means there's a list of one or more NBLs.

Put it all together, and you have:

- Your function receives a list of NBLs.
- Each NBL contains exactly 1 NB (on the receive path).
- Each NB contains a list of MDLs.
- Each MDL points to a buffer of payload.

So in our example code above, the for-loop iterates along that first bullet point: the chain of NBLs.  Within the loop, we only need to look at `nbl->FirstNetBuffer`, since we can safely assume there is no other nb besides the first.

It's inconvenient to have to fiddle with all those MDLs directly, so we use the helper routine `NdisGetDataBuffer`.  You tell this guy how many bytes of payload you want to see, and he'll give you a pointer to a contiguous range of payload.

- In the good case, your buffer is contained in a single MDL, so NdisGetDataBuffer just gives you a pointer back into that MDL's buffer.
- In the slow case, your buffer straddles more than one MDL, so NdisGetDataBuffer carefully copies the relevant bit of payload into a scratch buffer that you provided.

The latter case can be fiddly, if you're trying to inspect more than a few bytes.  If you're reading all 1500 bytes of the packet, you can't just allocate 1500 bytes on the stack (kernel stack space is scarce, unlike usermode), so you have to allocate it from the pool.  Once you figure that out, note it will slow things down to copy all 1500 bytes of data into a scratch buffer for every packet.  Is the slowdown too much?  It depends on your needs.  If you're only inspecting occasional packets, or if you're deploying the LWF on a low-throughput NIC, it won't matter.  If you're trying to get beyond 1Gbps, you shouldn't be memcpying so much data around.

Also note that if you ultimately want to *modify* the packet, you'll need to be wary of NdisGetDataBuffer.  It can give you a *copy* of the data (stored in your local scratch buffer), so if you modify the payload, those changes won't actually stick to the packet.

What if you *do* need to scale to high throughputs, or modify the payload?  Then you need to work out how to manipulate the MDL chain.  That's a bit confusing at first, but spend a little time with the documentation and draw yourself some whiteboard diagrams.

I suggest first starting out by understanding an MDL.  From networking's point of view, an MDL is just a fancy way of holding a { char * buffer, size_t length }, along with a link to the next MDL.

Next, consider the NB's DataOffset and DataLength.  These conceptually move the buffer boundaries in from the beginning and the end of the buffer.  They don't really care about MDL boundaries -- for example, you can reduce the length of the packet payload by decrementing DataLength, and if that means that one or more MDLs are no longer contributing any buffer space to the packet payload, it's no big deal, they're just ignored.

Finally, add on top CurrentMdl and CurrentMdlOffset.  These are redundant with everything above, but they exist for (microbenchmark) performance.  You aren't required to even think about them if you're reading the NB, but if you are editing the size of the NB, you do need to update them.

Comment: The answer helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi jeffrey, I have a virtual access point program on windows.. I want to edit beacons being sent out (for example change ssid for fun as an example)..can i do it with this filter? @JeffreyTippet